# How can I make this method on Selenide

Tags: java, selenide

Have this method in Selenium, now I want to rewrite it on Selenide but I can't find a solution. (Now it is on Java + Selenium)

```
 wait.until(driver1 -> !methodReturnText1().equals(methodReturnText2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be as simple as this:

```
Selenide.Wait().until(driver1 -> !methodReturnText1().equals(methodReturnText2));
```